# Unique and shared resource owner

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++14, raii

I need a `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` like structure, but instead of pointers, I would like to store some kind of reference to a resource. It is usually just an `int` and maybe some attributes. I would like to avoid using pointers, so these objects can be kept on the stack.

I usually use these containers in my OpenGL projects or with some C libraries, where I call a C function to allocate a resource, and then get back an ID or opaque pointer. If I do not need that resource anymore, then I have to call the appropriate deallocator function. In this case, the deallocator is called by the container.

**ResourceOwner:**

```
template<typename T>
class ResourceOwner {

    T data;

protected:

    ResourceOwner() : data() {}

public:

    // Disable copy
    ResourceOwner(const ResourceOwner&) = delete;
    ResourceOwner &operator=(const ResourceOwner&) = delete;

    // Move constructor
    ResourceOwner(ResourceOwner&& other) noexcept : data(other.Release())
    {}

    // Move operator
    ResourceOwner &operator=(ResourceOwner&& other) noexcept
    {
        Reset(other.Release());
        return *this;
    }

    // Delete resource
    void Reset(T&& new_data = T())
    {
        data.Reset();
        data = std::move(new_data);
    }

    // Get raw data
    const T& Get() const {
        return data;
    }

    ~ResourceOwner()
    {
        Reset();
    }

private:

    // Release ownership
    T Release()
    {
        T ret = std::move(data);
        data = T();
        return ret;
    }

};
```

The reference counter is a pointer in the `SharedResourceOwner`, but it is only created, when the second instance is created. The resource reference is not a pointer, because it is immutable, so it can be copied between shared owners.

**SharedResourceOwner:**

```
template<typename T>
class SharedResourceOwner {

    // number of owners except this
    mutable size_t* reference_counter = nullptr;
    // raw resource data
    T data = T();

protected:

    SharedResourceOwner() {}

public:

    ~SharedResourceOwner() {
        Reset();
    }

    // Copy constructor
    SharedResourceOwner(const SharedResourceOwner& other) noexcept {
        other.IncreaseCounter();

        reference_counter = other.reference_counter;
        data = other.data;
    }

    // Copy operator
    SharedResourceOwner &operator=(const SharedResourceOwner& other) noexcept {

        if (&other != this) {
            Reset();

            other.IncreaseCounter();

            reference_counter = other.reference_counter;
            data = other.data;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // Move constructor
    SharedResourceOwner(SharedResourceOwner &&other) noexcept
    {
        reference_counter = other.reference_counter;
        data = std::move(other.data);

        other.reference_counter = nullptr;
        other.data = T();
    }

    // Move operator
    SharedResourceOwner &operator=(SharedResourceOwner &&other) noexcept
    {
        Reset();

        reference_counter = other.reference_counter;
        data = std::move(other.data);

        other.reference_counter = nullptr;
        other.data = T();

        return *this;
    }

    // delete resource
    void Reset(T&& new_data = T()) {
        if (reference_counter == nullptr) {
            data.Reset();
        }
        else if (*reference_counter == 0) {
            delete reference_counter;
            data.Reset();
        }
        else {
            (*reference_counter)--;
        }

        reference_counter = nullptr;
        data = std::move(new_data);
    }

    // Get raw data
    const T& Get() const {
        return data;
    }

private:

    void IncreaseCounter() const {
        if (reference_counter == nullptr) {
            reference_counter = new size_t(0);
        }

        reference_counter++;

    }

};
```

The type `T` is a "ResourceReference" type. It is immutable inside the container. The content of the container may be reset or replaced, but its attributes cannot be changed, therefore you are only able to get a constant reference to it with `Get()`

---

**Example class**

An example type `T` looks like this:

```
struct TextureData {
    GLuint texture_id = 0;
    GLenum target = GL_TEXTURE_2D;

    TextureData() {}
    TextureData(GLuint texture_id) : texture_id(texture_id) {}

    void Reset() {
        if (texture_id > 0) {
            glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_id);
        }
    }
};
```

The contained classes are really simple, they only have some data members, and `Reset` is not expected to throw exception.

An example container:

```
class Texture : public ResourceOwner<TextureData> {

public:

    Texture() : ResourceOwner() {}

    GLuint GetId() const {
        return Get().texture_id;
    }

    // static helper function which returns a new image loaded from the path
    // defined in Texture.cpp
    static Texture FromFile(std::string path);

};
```

---

**Usage of the example class**

**app.hpp**:

```
#include "Texture.hpp"

class App {

    Texture myTexture;

    // ...

    void Init();
    void Render();

    // ...

}
```

**app.cpp**:

```
void App::Init() {

    myTexture = Texture::FromFile("example.jpg");

    // ...

}

void App::Render() {

    // ...

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(texture.Get().target, myTexture.GetId());
    SetUniform(tex_uniform_id, 0);

    // ...

}
```

---

**Example Texture creation**:

```
Texture createTextureFromData(
    std::vector<uint8_t> data,
    GLsizei width = 0,
    GLsizei height = 0
) {

    Texture texture
    TextureData texture_data;

    // Generate OpenGL texture
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_data.texture_id);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_data.texture_id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.data());

    // Generate mipmap
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //
    texture.Reset(std::move(texture_data));
    return texture;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example demonstrating the usage of the functionalities? (@chux-ReinstateMonica Done.)

Comment: I provided some examples

Comment: Can you make it a small but complete example? The example you presented in its current form is not meaningfully reviewable. We can only review real, working code. Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious to know if you've implemented VBOs yet, and how you handle passing the buffer component count and component type to `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: @user673679 Yes, I implemented containers for many OpenGL resources. But I am looking for feedbacks for the two ResourceOwner classes. Here you can see the other classes too with an example project: github.com/K-Adam/GLWrapper

Comment: @L.F. I would like to use the ResourceOwner classes for other C recourses too, not just for OpenGL related ones. That is why I did not include my whole library. A working OpenGL example code would be too long to post here, but it can be found here: github.com/K-Adam/GLWrapper/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 2):

**`ResourceOwner`:**

- We need to `#include <utility>` for `std::move`.
- `Reset` might be more flexible taking its argument by value `void Reset(T new_data = T())`, so we can copy into it instead of moving.
- It might be useful to have a value constructor: `ResourceOwner(T data);`.

**`SharedResourceOwner`:**

- Again, `#include <utility>`.
- Use `std::size_t` rather than `size_t` for C++.
- Use the constructor initializer list to initialize member variables, instead of assigning them in the body of the constructor.
- We could provide a `Swap()` function, allowing us to implement copy and move assignment more easily:

  ```
  void Swap(SharedResourceOwner& other)
  {
      using std::swap;
      swap(reference_counter, other.reference_counter);
      swap(data, other.data);
  }

  SharedResourceOwner &operator=(const SharedResourceOwner& other) noexcept
  {
      SharedResourceOwner temp(other);
      Swap(temp);
      return *this;
  }

  SharedResourceOwner &operator=(SharedResourceOwner &&other) noexcept
  {
      SharedResourceOwner temp(std::move(other));
      Swap(temp);
      return *this;
  }
  ```

  (We could do the same for `ResourceOwner`).
- Again, `Reset()` can take its parameter by value.
- I'm not sure it's worth the extra complication (extra logic in `Reset()`, and making the counter `mutable`) to avoid allocating the reference counter for the first instance. If we specify a `SharedResourceOwner` over a normal `ResourceOwner`, we probably need to use the reference counter anyway.

---

Some other points:

- The `TextureData` class might prefer to set `texture_id` to `0` after calling `glDeleteTextures` for added safety.
- Just resetting the owned data to a default constructed value is potentially dangerous. We have no easy way to ensure that `Get()` isn't called when the data is invalid.

  As well as storing `T data;` by value in the resource owner classes we could store a pointer to that same data member. The `Get()` function can then access the `data` member through the pointer, instead of directly. When the data is invalid (i.e. immediately after construction, after moving from the owner, after calling `Reset()`), we can make that pointer null. This would be a decent way of catching `Get()`s when the data is invalid.

  Alternatively, storing the data as `std::optional<T> data;` could do the same thing with less hassle.
- This looks like it copies the path string unnecessarily: `static Texture FromFile(std::string path);` we should pass it by `const&` instead of by value. (There are a lot of other places in the repository that do this).